# in regex get a single match just before the match pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a response like below

```
{"id":9,"announcementName":"Test","announcementText":"<p>TestAssertion</p>\n","effectiveStartDate":"03/01/2016","effectiveEndDate":"03/02/2016","updatedDate":"02/29/2016","status":"Active","moduleName":"Individual Portal"}
{"id":103,"announcementName":"d3mgcwtqhdu8003","announcementText":"<p>This announcement is a test announcement”,"effectiveStartDate":"03/01/2016","effectiveEndDate":"03/02/2016","updatedDate":"02/29/2016","status":"Active","moduleName":"Individual Portal"}
{"id":113,"announcementName":"asdfrtwju3f5gh7f21","announcementText":"<p>This announcement is a test announcement”,"effectiveStartDate":"03/02/2016","effectiveEndDate":"03/03/2016","updatedDate":"02/29/2016","status":"InActive","moduleName":"Individual Portal"}
```

I am trying get the value of id (103) of announcementName d3mgcwtqhdu8003.

I am using below regEx pattern to get the id

```
 "id":(.*?),"announcementName":"${announcementName}","announcementText":"
```

But it is matching everything from the first id to the announcementName. and returning

```
9,"announcementName":"Test","announcementText":"<p>TestAssertion</p>\n","effectiveStartDate":"03/01/2016","effectiveEndDate":"03/02/2016","updatedDate":"02/29/2016","status":"Active","moduleName":"Individual Portal"}
{"id":103,"announcementName":"d3mgcwtqhdu8003","announcementText":
```

But I want to match only from the id **just before** the required announcementName.

How can I do this in RegEx . Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: ps:unable to frame a correct question title for this. :-/

Comment: can you add a specific language tag ?(javascript ??)

Comment: Isn't this `JSON` ? Why don't you use an appropriate parser? If not, the IDs are numeric, sth. as simple as `"id":(\d+)` [will probably do](https://regex101.com/r/iQ5jL0/1).

Answer (score 0):

As an answer here as well. Either use appropriate `JSON` functions, if not, a simple regex like:

```
"id":(\d+)
```

[will probably do](https://regex101.com/r/iQ5jL0/1) as the IDs are numeric.